# data not shown in my JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

The scrollbar and the button will be painted but not the cells in the table,and the console has printed the data correctly so I am wondering where I have done wrong.

```
public class MyGUIManager extends JPanel {

    protected JFrame frame;
    protected JScrollPane scrollPane=null;
    protected JTable table=null;
    protected TableModel model=null;
    protected JButton btnInsert=null;

    protected String dbname,tblname;
    protected Vector<String> colNames;
    protected Vector<Vector<String>> data,backup;
    protected int col;

    protected MySQLGUIManager() throws Exception{

        frame =new JFrame("MySQL Manager");
        frame.setContentPane(this);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        init();
    }

    protected void init() throws Exception{
        //some inrrelevant operations about database
        loadTbl();
    }

    protected void loadTbl() throws SQLException{
        table=new JTable(data,colNames){
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e){
                int column=e.getColumn();
                assert e.getFirstRow()==e.getLastRow():"more than 1 row have been changed!";
                int row=e.getFirstRow();
                if(scrollPane!=null){
                    //some codes
                }
            }
        };

        model=table.getModel();
        scrollPane=new JScrollPane(table,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        btnInsert=new JButton("Insert a row");
        add(btnInsert,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        repaint();
        revalidate();
//      scrollPane.repaint();
//      scrollPane.revalidate();
        System.out.println(model.getColumnCount()+" "+model.getRowCount());
        for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
            for(int j=0;j<data.get(0).size();j++){
                System.out.print(model.getValueAt(i, j)+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new MySQLGUIManager();
    }

}
```

(Some codes are omitted but they have nothing to do with GUI.)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: First question: Why all those protected void's and why is your constructor protected?

Comment: @brano88 Why is he constructing a `JFrame` from within a `JPanel` and adding it self to it??

Comment: Your sample doesn't actually load anything into the table...

Comment: Try creating a `DefaultTableModel` and seeding that to the table first and see what data is return from `table.getModel`

Comment: If my sample doesn't load anything into the table,wouldn't the System.out.print codes on the bottom fail?

Comment: You're not calling 'super.tableChanged'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Nothing is added to the data/column models
- The data and column models are uninitialized
- Creating a `JFrame` from within a `JPanel` only to add itself to the frame is bad practice

You're not call `super.tableChanged` from within you `tableChanged` method

```
table = new JTable(data, colNames) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
        super.tableChanged(e);
        int column = e.getColumn();
        assert e.getFirstRow() == e.getLastRow() : "more than 1 row have been changed!";
        int row = e.getFirstRow();
        if (scrollPane != null) {
            //some codes
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: its actually the problem about super.tableChanged.Thx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anywhere in the code where you actually add the table to any of the UI's existing containers.

Also, it's probably a good idea to create the table and add it to it's intended parent component before calling pack().

You might want to think about separating the creation of the table from loading the data.

Also, the omitted "some codes" may have have a very large effect on the behavior of the table, so be careful there.

Comment: I called the constructor JScrollPane(Component,int,int) to add table.It is in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok...here is an example how to fill your table using `DefaultTableModel` model because your pseudo SSCCE is useless:

```
package com.model.impl;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class FillTable extends JFrame{

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name: ");
    JLabel lblIp = new JLabel("Ip: ");
    JTextField txtName = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField txtIp = new JTextField(10);
    JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
    JTable table = new JTable();
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{}, new String[]{"Name","Ip"});

    public FillTable(){
        super("Test table");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(panel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(lblName);
        panel.add(txtName);
        panel.add(lblIp);
        panel.add(txtIp);
        panel.add(btnAdd);
        table.setModel(model);
        add(new JScrollPane(table),BorderLayout.CENTER);

        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String name = txtName.getText();
                String ip = txtIp.getText();

                model.addRow(new Object[]{name,ip});
            }});
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                FillTable ft = new FillTable();
                ft.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                ft.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                ft.pack();
                ft.setVisible(true);
            }});
    }
}
```

I hope it will help. Good luck!